# Redirect any possible domain request to the root

Tags: .htaccess

I have mydomain.com. Im looking to redirect any request to the root being either just: mydomain.com or mydomain.com/index.html

With any request - I mean everything. Could be request to:

```
mydomain.com?hello
mydomain.com/subdir/ (im not sure if that will conflict with linking to assets in my index.html?)
mydomain/gwegewgewgew/
mydomain.com/hello.jpg
etc
```

I've tried with the following but no luck:

```
RewriteEngine On

# It is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# It is a directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# If request is for other than root then route to /
RewriteRule .+ / [L]
```

If I try and request: mydomain.com/teteetegeg - **I just get: "The requested URL /teetege was not found on this server."**

Have checked the mod_rewrite is appearing under loaded modules with php info.

Comment: If I try and request: mydomain.com/teteetegeg - I just get: "The requested URL /teetege was not found on this server."

Comment: You mean replace the current RewriteRule with that? Just tried that with same result

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(?:index\.html)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R]
```

Or, you can use fallback resource:

```
FallbackResource /
```